# How to distinguish a good sine wave from a distorted one from a solenoid signal?

Tags: signal-detection, motion, motion-detection

I have a rotating magnet in front of an iron-core solenoid. When the magnet rotates, it would reduce speed, and then it will stop spinning and just sway back and forth. I want to know when it stops spinning from the signal. When it spins the signal looks like attenuating sine wave, and then the signal distort. Sorry I don't have a better word to describe so please check the plotting image.

Ideally this can be solved in time domain, as the algorithm need to run on a low end micro-controller.

Thanks in advance.

Here is a the signal.

[image]

And here is the data if you may want to run it.

`[419, 423, 424, 425, 428, 431, 435, 435, 440, 445, 447, 452, 457, 460, 466, 471, 477, 482, 489, 493, 501, 508, 513, 520, 526, 533, 539, 545, 550, 558, 563, 571, 574, 579, 585, 590, 595, 602, 605, 608, 612, 615, 618, 620, 624, 628, 632, 633, 634, 634, 636, 638, 639, 639, 640, 640, 639, 640, 640, 640, 641, 638, 637, 637, 636, 635, 634, 635, 633, 630, 628, 630, 628, 628, 617, 621, 620, 620, 616, 613, 612, 610, 608, 605, 599, 597, 594, 589, 583, 580, 575, 571, 568, 561, 556, 552, 546, 541, 536, 531, 523, 518, 513, 505, 500, 495, 489, 483, 478, 474, 467, 463, 458, 454, 448, 446, 442, 437, 438, 432, 427, 426, 424, 422, 418, 418, 416, 414, 409, 411, 411, 410, 410, 408, 409, 408, 407, 407, 406, 408, 408, 407, 408, 407, 407, 406, 408, 407, 409, 410, 409, 411, 408, 412, 411, 413, 412, 413, 417, 416, 417, 418, 420, 421, 423, 424, 426, 426, 429, 432, 435, 440, 441, 445, 448, 451, 455, 459, 464, 468, 472, 478, 481, 486, 494, 500, 505, 512, 516, 522, 527, 533, 538, 543, 550, 555, 561, 567, 571, 576, 582, 587, 589, 593, 597, 604, 605, 605, 610, 612, 614, 618, 619, 624, 624, 627, 625, 627, 627, 629, 629, 629, 630, 629, 629, 630, 628, 628, 627, 629, 627, 626, 626, 626, 625, 624, 624, 624, 623, 620, 620, 617, 616, 616, 614, 612, 613, 613, 608, 607, 603, 601, 598, 595, 592, 590, 589, 585, 582, 579, 575, 571, 568, 563, 557, 555, 550, 546, 540, 536, 530, 525, 520, 516, 512, 504, 500, 494, 488, 483, 480, 474, 471, 466, 464, 458, 452, 450, 450, 442, 440, 439, 436, 434, 433, 430, 427, 425, 424, 424, 421, 422, 421, 421, 419, 418, 418, 419, 418, 417, 418, 418, 417, 418, 419, 418, 420, 418, 418, 420, 419, 419, 419, 420, 420, 420, 421, 421, 420, 423, 422, 424, 425, 424, 423, 424, 425, 427, 427, 428, 429, 430, 431, 432, 434, 435, 437, 440, 441, 443, 445, 449, 453, 455, 459, 461, 465, 469, 473, 477, 482, 486, 492, 496, 501, 505, 512, 517, 522, 528, 533, 536, 540, 549, 552, 555, 560, 565, 570, 573, 579, 581, 585, 589, 592, 596, 600, 601, 603, 604, 607, 611, 612, 616, 615, 616, 619, 620, 619, 620, 620, 620, 619, 620, 621, 619, 619, 619, 618, 620, 619, 619, 619, 619, 619, 616, 614, 614, 614, 613, 612, 612, 612, 610, 609, 608, 606, 607, 605, 603, 602, 601, 600, 599, 597, 596, 594, 592, 588, 587, 584, 584, 579, 577, 574, 572, 567, 564, 561, 556, 554, 550, 545, 541, 537, 532, 529, 525, 519, 515, 509, 504, 501, 498, 493, 490, 485, 478, 476, 474, 466, 463, 462, 458, 456, 454, 450, 448, 445, 442, 440, 438, 435, 439, 435, 434, 433, 431, 432, 430, 429, 427, 427, 430, 426, 427, 427, 428, 429, 428, 429, 428, 428, 429, 429, 429, 430, 431, 431, 431, 430, 431, 431, 431, 432, 433, 432, 431, 431, 431, 433, 433, 432, 434, 433, 433, 435, 436, 436, 435, 435, 436, 436, 438, 440, 439, 439, 444, 442, 444, 445, 446, 449, 449, 452, 453, 457, 458, 461, 465, 467, 470, 472, 476, 480, 485, 489, 492, 494, 500, 504, 508, 514, 519, 524, 528, 532, 536, 541, 546, 548, 553, 558, 564, 566, 569, 571, 577, 581, 584, 585, 588, 590, 594, 596, 598, 599, 602, 604, 606, 604, 606, 607, 607, 609, 610, 609, 610, 608, 610, 608, 609, 611, 610, 608, 608, 607, 606, 607, 608, 607, 607, 605, 604, 604, 604, 602, 601, 601, 601, 601, 600, 600, 600, 599, 598, 597, 597, 598, 596, 594, 593, 592, 592, 591, 590, 590, 588, 586, 584, 584, 582, 580, 580, 577, 575, 572, 570, 567, 565, 562, 559, 556, 554, 549, 547, 544, 538, 536, 533, 528, 525, 521, 518, 515, 509, 504, 500, 500, 493, 489, 488, 484, 480, 478, 474, 470, 468, 464, 462, 459, 457, 454, 454, 450, 449, 445, 446, 446, 444, 442, 443, 442, 441, 439, 439, 439, 438, 439, 439, 439, 440, 438, 438, 439, 440, 440, 440, 441, 441, 442, 442, 442, 441, 443, 444, 444, 444, 445, 445, 444, 446, 446, 446, 445, 446, 446, 446, 447, 445, 446, 446, 447, 447, 448, 447, 447, 447, 447, 447, 447, 448, 448, 447, 448, 446, 448, 447, 447, 448, 449, 449, 449, 451, 451, 452, 452, 453, 455, 455, 456, 459, 460, 461, 463, 466, 466, 471, 472, 475, 478, 480, 482, 486, 490, 492, 496, 500, 503, 507, 512, 515, 519, 523, 526, 529, 535, 539, 542, 545, 549, 553, 557, 560, 563, 566, 568, 572, 576, 577, 580, 582, 586, 587, 587, 591, 591, 592, 592, 594, 596, 596, 596, 596, 597, 599, 598, 598, 598, 598, 597, 597, 597, 593, 596, 599, 597, 595, 596, 594, 594, 592, 592, 591, 592, 590, 588, 589, 591, 589, 587, 589, 588, 588, 587, 586, 586, 586, 586, 587, 585, 584, 585, 585, 583, 584, 584, 583, 582, 582, 582, 582, 581, 580, 580, 578, 579, 577, 576, 576, 575, 574, 573, 571, 572, 569, 568, 566, 564, 561, 560, 558, 556, 553, 551, 548, 547, 544, 539, 537, 535, 532, 529, 526, 522, 519, 518, 514, 508, 505, 504, 502, 496, 493, 491, 489, 485, 482, 481, 477, 476, 472, 470, 469, 467, 464, 462, 462, 462, 458, 457, 456, 455, 455, 454, 454, 452, 451, 452, 452, 452, 451, 451, 452, 451, 452, 453, 451, 452, 452, 454, 454, 454, 455, 455, 455, 456, 456, 457, 458, 457, 459, 459, 460, 460, 460, 462, 461, 463, 462, 463, 464, 463, 464, 464, 464, 465, 465, 465, 465, 465, 465, 465, 466, 464, 465, 465, 465, 465, 467, 465, 464, 465, 464, 465, 465, 465, 464, 465, 465, 465, 464, 464, 462, 462, 462, 463, 462, 462, 462, 462, 463, 463, 460, 461, 461, 461, 461, 461, 462, 462, 462, 463, 463, 464, 465, 466, 466, 467, 468, 470, 471, 472, 472, 475, 477, 479, 480, 482, 484, 486, 489, 491, 496, 497, 499, 503, 505, 509, 513, 516, 520, 523, 525, 528, 532, 535, 537, 540, 544, 546, 549, 552, 554, 557, 561, 564, 565, 567, 570, 571, 573, 575, 577, 578, 578, 579, 581, 581, 583, 584, 582, 585, 585, 584, 585, 586, 585, 585, 584, 584, 585, 584, 584, 582, 581, 581, 580, 580, 581, 580, 579, 579, 577, 576, 577, 574, 575, 573, 573, 573, 573, 572, 571, 572, 570, 570, 570, 569, 568, 568, 569, 567, 569, 567, 568, 567, 567, 567, 567, 567, 566, 568, 567, 565, 567, 567, 567, 567, 566, 568, 567, 566, 567, 567, 566, 567, 567, 567, 566, 567, 567, 565, 566, 565, 567, 566, 565, 565, 565, 564, 564, 564, 563, 564, 563, 558, 556, 558, 558, 555, 556, 554, 552, 550, 550, 547, 546, 545, 543, 540, 537, 536, 533, 531, 528, 527, 524, 521, 517, 516, 514, 512, 508, 506, 504, 501, 499, 496, 493, 491, 490, 488, 487, 483, 481, 480, 480, 478, 475, 473, 473, 470, 469, 470, 469, 468, 468, 465, 465, 464, 464, 465, 465, 463, 465, 464, 464, 465, 465, 465, 466, 465, 466, 466, 466, 467, 468, 468, 469, 470, 470, 471, 473, 472, 473, 474, 475, 475, 476, 477, 478, 478, 479, 479, 480, 481, 481, 483, 484, 484, 485, 486, 486, 487, 487, 487, 488, 489, 489, 490, 489, 491, 492, 492, 492, 493, 494, 494, 495, 495, 495, 495, 496, 496, 497, 495, 497, 497, 499, 498, 499, 499, 500, 500, 499, 500, 500, 501, 501, 501, 501, 502, 501, 501, 502, 502, 502, 503, 502, 503, 502, 503, 503, 503, 503, 503, 502, 503, 503, 503, 503, 503, 503, 503, 503, 503, 502, 502, 502, 503, 502, 503, 503, 503, 503, 502, 502, 502, 502, 501, 502, 501, 501, 502, 500, 501, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 499, 499, 499, 499, 497, 497, 497, 497, 497, 496, 496, 495, 495, 495, 494, 494, 494, 493, 493, 493, 492, 492, 491, 490, 490, 490, 490, 489, 488, 488, 487, 486, 486, 486, 485, 486, 484, 484, 483, 482, 482, 480, 480, 480, 480, 479, 479, 478, 478, 476, 476, 476, 476, 475, 475, 474, 474, 474, 474, 474, 473, 474, 473, 475, 474, 474, 473, 475, 475, 475, 477, 478, 478, 478, 480, 481, 482, 484, 486, 487, 489, 490, 491, 492, 494, 497, 501, 503, 504, 507, 509, 512, 514, 516, 518, 521, 524, 526, 529, 531, 534, 536, 539, 541, 544, 546, 547, 550, 553, 554, 556, 558, 560, 562, 564, 563, 564, 566, 568, 569, 569, 569, 571, 571, 572, 571, 571, 572, 572, 572, 571, 573, 572, 572, 572, 571, 570, 570, 570, 569, 569, 567, 567, 566, 565, 564, 565, 563, 560, 561, 561, 560, 559, 557, 557, 557, 556, 555, 553, 553, 553, 551, 551, 550, 548, 549, 548, 548, 547, 546, 546, 544, 544, 544, 543, 541, 542, 541, 540, 541, 539, 539, 539, 538, 537, 536, 537, 536, 536, 536, 536, 536, 536, 535, 534, 533, 534, 533, 533, 532, 533, 533, 533, 533, 532, 532, 532, 532, 532, 532, 532, 532, 532, 532, 532, 532, 531, 532, 532, 531, 532, 533, 532, 533, 532, 532, 533, 533, 533, 533, 534, 533, 533, 533, 533, 534, 534, 535, 535, 535, 535, 535, 536, 536, 536, 537, 538, 537, 538, 537, 538, 539, 539, 539, 540, 540, 541, 541, 542, 541, 542, 543, 543, 544, 544, 544, 545, 545, 546, 545, 545, 547, 546, 548, 548, 549, 548, 549, 549, 549, 549, 551, 551, 550, 551, 551, 550, 550, 549, 549, 550, 549, 550, 549, 549, 549, 549, 548, 547, 547, 545, 545, 545, 544, 542, 542, 541, 539, 537, 538, 536, 536, 533, 531, 530, 528, 527, 525, 524, 522, 520, 518, 517, 515, 512, 512, 508, 507, 506, 503, 502, 500, 498, 497, 496, 493, 492, 491, 489, 488, 486, 487, 484, 483, 482, 480, 480, 479, 479, 477, 478, 478, 477, 477, 477, 476, 476, 477, 476, 476, 477, 478, 478, 478, 479, 479, 479, 480, 480, 480, 481, 482, 483, 482, 485, 485, 485, 486, 487, 488, 489, 490, 490, 491, 492, 493, 495, 495, 496, 498, 499, 500, 500, 501, 501, 502, 503, 505, 505, 506, 508, 508, 509, 512, 512, 513, 514, 515, 516, 516, 518, 518, 519, 521, 521, 522, 523, 524, 525, 526, 527, 527, 528, 529, 529, 532, 532, 534, 534, 535, 536, 537, 538, 538, 539, 540, 541, 542, 543, 544, 545, 545, 546, 546, 547, 548, 549, 550, 549, 550, 551, 551, 551, 552, 552, 553, 553, 552, 553, 554, 553, 552, 552, 552, 552, 552, 551, 551, 551, 551, 549, 548, 548, 547, 546, 545, 543, 542, 542, 540, 539, 536, 535, 534, 532, 531, 530, 527, 526, 524, 523, 521, 519, 518, 516, 515, 513, 512, 508, 507, 506, 506, 504, 501, 500, 499, 499, 498, 496, 496, 494, 492, 492, 492, 490, 490, 489, 489, 489, 489, 487, 487, 487, 488, 487, 487, 488, 487, 488, 487, 487, 488, 488, 488, 486, 487, 487, 488, 488, 488, 488, 490, 490, 492, 492, 492, 493, 493, 495, 495, 495, 495, 496, 497, 498, 499, 499, 499, 500, 501, 502, 502, 503, 503, 504, 505, 505, 506, 507, 507, 508, 509, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 513, 513, 515, 516, 516, 517, 518, 517, 519, 519, 520, 520, 520, 522, 521, 522, 523, 524, 524, 525, 525, 526, 527, 528, 528, 529, 530, 530, 530, 531, 531, 532, 533, 533, 534, 535, 535, 536, 537, 536, 537, 538, 538, 539, 540, 540, 541, 541, 542, 543, 543, 543, 542, 541, 542, 543, 542, 543, 542, 542, 542, 543, 543, 543, 543, 541, 542, 541, 541, 540, 540, 540, 539, 538, 537, 537, 535, 534, 534, 533, 531, 530, 530, 529, 526, 524, 524, 522, 521, 520, 518, 517, 515, 514, 513, 512, 508, 507, 505, 504, 503, 502, 500, 499, 498, 497, 495, 493, 492, 491, 491, 489, 488, 487, 486, 485, 485, 485, 484, 484, 483, 482, 482, 482, 482, 482, 482, 482, 483, 482, 482, 483, 483, 483, 484, 485, 484, 485, 486, 487, 487, 487, 488, 489, 490, 490, 492, 492, 492, 494, 494, 495, 495, 498, 498, 499, 500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 509, 509, 512, 513, 513, 514, 516, 516, 517, 518, 520, 520, 521, 521, 523, 524, 525, 525, 527, 528, 529, 529, 531, 531, 532, 533, 534, 535, 535, 536, 537, 538, 538, 541, 540, 540, 542, 541, 544, 544, 544, 545, 545, 545, 547, 546, 546, 547, 548, 547, 548, 548, 547, 548, 548, 547, 547, 547, 547, 543, 545, 546, 545, 544, 544, 542, 542, 541, 540, 539, 538, 537, 536, 534, 533, 532, 531, 529, 528, 526, 526, 524, 523, 521, 520, 519, 517, 516, 514, 513, 512, 509, 508, 508, 507, 505, 503, 503, 502, 501, 500, 498, 498, 498, 496, 495, 495, 494, 494, 494, 493, 493, 493, 492, 492, 491, 491, 492, 491, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 492, 493, 494, 495, 494, 495, 496, 495, 494, 494, 496, 496, 497, 497, 498, 499, 500, 501, 501, 502, 503, 503, 504, 505, 506, 506, 506, 507, 508, 508, 509, 512, 512, 512, 513, 514, 514, 515, 516, 516, 517, 518, 518, 519, 520, 520, 521, 521, 522, 523, 524, 524, 525, 525, 527, 527, 528, 528, 529, 529, 531, 531, 532, 533, 533, 534, 534, 535, 535, 536, 534, 535, 535, 536, 537, 537, 537, 537, 537, 537, 537, 537, 538, 538, 537, 538, 538, 538, 537, 537, 537, 536, 536, 536, 536, 535, 535, 534, 532, 531, 532, 531, 530, 528, 528, 527, 527, 524, 523, 521, 521, 520, 519, 518, 517, 515, 514, 512, 512, 509, 509, 507, 506, 505, 504, 502, 501, 500, 499, 498, 497, 496, 495, 493, 493, 492, 491, 491, 489, 489, 489, 488, 487, 487, 488, 488, 487, 486, 487, 486, 487, 487, 486, 487, 487, 488, 488, 489, 489, 489, 490, 490, 491, 491, 492, 493, 493, 494, 495, 495, 495, 496, 498, 498, 499, 499, 501, 501, 503, 503, 505, 506, 507, 507, 508, 509, 512, 512, 513, 514, 515, 515, 516, 517, 519, 519, 520, 520, 522, 523, 524, 524, 525, 526, 528, 528, 529, 530, 530, 531, 532, 533, 533, 534, 535, 536, 537, 537, 538, 538, 539, 540, 540, 540, 540, 541, 542, 541, 542, 541, 542, 543, 543, 544, 543, 543, 544, 542, 542, 542, 543, 543, 543, 541, 540, 540, 539, 538, 538, 537, 536, 536, 534, 533, 533, 532, 530, 529, 528, 527, 525, 525, 523, 523, 520, 520, 519, 517, 517, 515, 513, 513, 512, 509, 509, 512, 507, 506, 505, 504, 503, 502, 501, 502, 501, 499, 499, 499, 498, 497, 497, 498, 497, 496, 497, 496, 496, 496, 496, 495, 496, 496, 496, 496, 496, 496, 497, 497, 498, 498, 498, 499, 499, 500, 500, 500, 500, 501, 501, 502, 503, 503, 504, 505, 505, 506, 505, 506, 507, 508, 508, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 514, 515, 515, 516, 516, 518, 518, 519, 520, 519, 521, 522, 522, 523, 523, 523, 524, 525, 524, 525, 526, 527, 527, 528, 529, 529, 529, 529, 530, 531, 531, 531, 531, 532, 533, 533, 534, 533, 533, 533, 534, 534, 533, 534, 533, 534, 534, 533, 533, 533, 533, 532, 532, 532, 532, 530, 530, 530, 528, 528, 528, 527, 526, 525, 524, 523, 522, 521, 521, 519, 519, 518, 516, 516, 515, 514, 512, 512, 512, 508, 507, 506, 505, 504, 503, 503, 502, 501, 499, 499, 498, 497, 497, 496, 495, 494, 495, 493, 492, 492, 492, 490, 490, 491, 491, 491, 491, 491, 491, 490, 491, 491, 491, 491, 491, 492, 492, 492, 493, 494, 494, 494, 495, 496, 496, 497, 497, 498, 499, 499, 500, 501, 502, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 506, 508, 508, 509, 512, 512, 512, 514, 515, 515, 516, 517, 518, 519, 519, 520, 521, 522, 522, 524, 524, 525, 527, 527, 527, 529, 530, 530, 530, 531, 532, 533, 533, 535, 534, 535, 536, 536, 537, 537, 537, 537, 537, 538, 538, 539, 539, 539, 539, 539, 539, 539, 538, 539, 539, 539, 539, 538, 538, 537, 536, 536, 536, 535, 534, 534, 534, 532, 532, 530, 529, 528, 530, 527, 526, 525, 524, 524, 522, 521, 521, 519, 519, 518, 516, 515, 514, 513, 512, 512, 512, 512, 509, 508, 507, 506, 505, 505, 504, 503, 503, 502, 502, 501, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 501, 500, 500, 498, 499, 499, 499, 500, 499, 500, 500, 501, 501, 500, 500, 500, 502, 501, 502, 502, 503, 503, 503, 504, 504, 505, 505, 506, 506, 507, 508, 508, 509, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 513, 514, 514, 514, 515, 516, 516, 517, 517, 518, 519, 519, 519, 520, 521, 521, 521, 522, 523, 523, 523, 524, 524, 525, 526, 526, 527, 527, 527, 528, 528, 529, 529, 529, 530, 528, 529, 530, 531, 530, 530, 531, 530, 530, 531, 531, 530, 530, 530, 530, 529, 530, 529, 529, 528, 528, 528, 527, 527, 526, 525, 524, 523, 522, 522, 522, 520, 519, 519, 519, 518, 517, 516, 515, 514, 513, 512, 512, 509, 508, 508, 507, 506, 505, 504, 504, 503, 503, 501, 500, 500, 499, 499, 498, 498, 497, 497, 496, 496, 495, 494, 494, 495, 495, 494, 494, 494, 493, 494, 494, 495, 495, 495, 494, 495, 495, 496, 495, 497, 497, 498, 498, 498, 499, 500, 500, 501, 501, 502, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 507, 508, 508, 512, 512, 512, 512, 513, 514, 515, 516, 517, 517, 518, 519, 520, 521, 522, 522, 523, 524, 524, 524, 525, 526, 526, 528, 528, 529, 528, 530, 531, 531, 532, 532, 532, 533, 533, 534, 534, 535, 535, 535, 536, 536, 535, 535, 536, 535, 536, 537, 536, 536, 536, 536, 535, 535, 535, 535, 535, 534, 532, 532, 532, 531, 530, 529, 530, 528, 527, 527, 527, 525, 525, 524, 523, 522, 521, 520, 520, 519, 519, 518, 516, 515, 515, 514, 513, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 509, 508, 507, 507, 506, 505, 505, 505, 504, 504, 503, 503, 503, 503, 503, 503, 503, 502, 502, 502, 502, 502, 503, 502, 503, 502, 503, 503, 503, 504, 503, 504, 504, 505, 505, 505, 506, 506, 506, 507, 508, 509, 508, 509, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 513, 514, 514, 515, 515, 516, 516, 517, 517, 518, 519, 518, 519, 519, 520, 521, 520, 521, 521, 522, 522, 523, 523, 524, 524, 524, 525, 525, 526, 526, 527, 527, 527, 527, 528, 528, 527, 529, 527, 528, 528, 527, 527, 527, 528, 528, 527, 527, 527, 526, 526, 526, 526, 525, 524, 525, 524, 523, 521, 522, 521, 520, 520, 519, 519, 519, 518, 516, 516, 515, 514, 513, 514, 512, 512, 512, 509, 512, 508, 508, 506, 506, 505, 504, 504, 503, 503, 502, 501, 501, 500, 500, 499, 500, 498, 498, 498, 498, 497, 495, 496, 497, 497, 497, 496, 497, 497, 497, 497, 498, 497, 498, 499, 498, 499, 499, 500, 500, 501, 501, 501, 501, 503, 503, 504, 504, 505, 505, 506, 507, 507, 508, 508, 509, 509, 512, 512, 513, 513, 514, 514, 516, 517, 517, 517, 517, 519, 519, 520, 521, 521, 522, 522, 522, 525, 525, 526, 526, 526, 527, 527, 528, 528, 528, 529, 530, 531, 531, 530, 532, 531, 530, 532, 532, 532, 532, 532, 533, 533, 533, 533, 533, 533, 533, 533, 533, 532, 531, 532, 531, 531, 531, 530, 529, 529, 528, 528, 527, 527, 527, 524, 525, 524, 524, 523, 523, 522, 521, 520, 519, 519, 518, 517, 517, 517, 515, 515, 514, 513, 513, 513, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 509, 508, 507, 507, 506, 507, 506, 505, 506, 505, 505, 505, 505, 505, 504, 504, 505, 504, 505, 505, 505, 505, 505, 506, 505, 505, 506, 506, 506, 507, 507, 507, 508, 508, 508, 508, 509, 509, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 513, 513, 513, 514, 514, 515, 515, 516, 517, 517, 517, 518, 518, 519, 519, 519, 519, 520, 520, 521, 522, 522, 522, 522, 523, 524, 523, 522, 524, 524, 524, 525, 524, 525, 525, 525, 525, 526, 525, 525, 525, 525, 525, 525, 525, 525, 524, 524, 524, 524, 524, 524, 523, 523, 521, 521, 521, 521, 520, 519, 519, 519, 519, 518, 517, 516, 516, 515, 514, 513, 513, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 509, 508, 508, 506, 506, 506, 505, 504, 504, 504, 503, 503, 502, 503, 501, 500, 501, 501, 500, 501, 500, 500, 500, 499, 499, 499, 499, 499, 499, 500, 499, 500, 500, 501, 500, 501, 501, 502, 502, 502, 502, 503, 504, 503, 504, 505, 505, 506, 507, 506, 507, 508, 508, 509, 509, 512, 512, 512, 512, 514, 514, 515, 515, 516, 516, 517, 518, 518, 519, 519, 520, 521, 519, 522, 522, 523, 522, 524, 524, 524, 525, 526, 525, 526, 526, 528, 527, 528, 528, 528, 529, 529, 529, 529, 530, 530, 530, 530, 531, 532, 530, 531, 531, 531, 530, 530, 529, 528, 529, 529, 528, 528, 528, 528, 527, 526, 526, 526, 526, 524, 525, 524, 523, 522, 522, 521, 522, 521, 520, 520, 519, 518, 518, 517, 517, 517, 515, 515, 514, 513, 513, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 509, 509, 508, 508, 508, 508, 507, 507, 507, 507, 507, 507, 507, 506, 507, 506, 507, 508, 507, 507, 507, 507, 507, 508, 508, 508, 507, 508, 509, 509, 512, 509, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 513, 513, 513, 513, 514, 515, 515, 515, 515, 516, 516, 517, 518, 517, 517, 518, 519, 519, 520, 519, 520, 520, 520, 521, 521, 521, 521, 523, 522, 522, 522, 522, 523, 523, 523, 523, 523, 523, 524, 523, 523, 523, 523, 523, 523, 523, 522, 523, 523, 521, 521, 521, 521, 521, 520, 520, 519, 519, 519, 519, 519, 518, 517, 517]`

Comment: It looks like there is a certain frequency at which the magnet starts to "wobble". If this frequency is constant, you would just need to know it, count the zero crossings, calculate the spinning frequency and compare both values.

Comment: @Max Thanks. I tried to do zero crossing and check when the period decrease (slow down) then increases (wobble). It did work and I'm curious to see if there another approach.